# How does C++ deal with Multiple inheritance( NOT the diamond one)

Tags: c++

C++ can solve the problem of multiple inheritance using the concept of virtual base class. But everywhere I have seen that the diamond problem is used to illustrate the use of virtual base classes. Take this example given below. This is also a multiple inheritance. But how can this be solved using virtual base classes? This is giving compilation error. Please someone point out the mistake i am doing. 
Thank you

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Parent1 {
    public:
         void fun();
};

void Parent1::fun(){
    cout<<"Parent1"<<endl;
}
class Parent2{
    public: void fun()
    {
        cout<<"Parent2"<<endl;
    }
};

class Child:public virtual Parent1,public virtual Parent2
{

};
int main()
{
    Child c;
    c.fun();
}
```

Comment: Multiple inheritance is about the fact that you derived from more than one class, not about the fact that there are functions with the same name. The _problem of multiple inheritance_ does not exist.

Comment: Yes you are right. But we might end up facing such problem as a consequence. That is why i thought of asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with inheritance, there is just a name conflict which may be easily solved.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Parent1 {
public:
    void fun() {
        cout << "Parent1" << endl;
    }
};

class Parent2 {
public:
    void fun() {
        cout<<"Parent2"<<endl;
    }
};

class Child:public virtual Parent1,public virtual Parent2
{
public:
    using Parent1::fun;
};

int main()
{
    Child c;
    c.fun();
}
```

Comment: And either way, you can still fully qualify the member `c.Parent2::fun();`